# i authenticate user phone with firebase its working fine but suddenly i face problem i search a lot but find nothing. this is the exception message

Tags: java, android

This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.

```
       @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Log.d("firebase_auth_error", e.getMessage());
            kProgressHUD.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

---

```
E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are 
            blocked.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "forbidden"
          }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
      }
    }
 403`enter code here`
```

Comment: try using a lower version for Firebase Auth - `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'`

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com

Enable --> Android Device Verification